# Log error in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have asp.net Web application where in we are calling SSRS Report and showing it in Report Viewer Control on aspx page. I got the following error in log. Can anyone help me finding root cause for the same.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: The report execution rs3enq55nl1zcu55tprb5zmo has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession() at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.LoadViewState(Object viewStateObj) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups() at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.
>   Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at MerrillLynch.Framework.Integration.MLIFSessionDBBase.DeserializeObject(Byte[] data) at MerrillLynch.Framework.Integration.MLIFLegacyStateDB.GetSessionStateItem(String SessionID, String SessionStateID) at MerrillLynch.Framework.Integration.MLIFLegacyStateDB.Get(String SessionID, String SessionStateID, String SessionStateName) at MerrillLynch.Framework.Integration.Session.GetSessionData(CSessionKeyInfo oCSessionKeyInfo) at MerrillLynch.Framework.Integration.MLIFSession.GetSimple(String key)

Comment: is that report working if you try directly from report server?

Comment: Yes...it is working perfectly if i try it from report server